# Searching inside sql file with node js

Tags: javascript

After reading the sql file, I want to search for a word and print the line of the found word to the console, how can I do it?

just like ctrl + f in note pad

`

Comment: well it can tell you the character index where the string was found, not sure about the line

Comment: print the text in the character index to the console